# Visual Studio 2013 Manual Testing using .testsettings

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, testing, visual-studio-2013, manual

I see that only 3 test projects exist.

1. Coded UI Test Project
2. Unit Test Project
3. Web Performance and Load Test Project

I have setup a .testsettings file for my solution that enables Network Emulation ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505008.aspx))

In order to start up network emulation I have to run one of the test projects listed above, all of the above test projects are designed for automatic testing. I want to be able to debug and test my project(s) manually while Network Emulation is on, currently the only way to do that is to create a Unit Test, start it, and then just call the other projects Main method (that I want to manually), the problem with this is that sometimes the program's UI does not show (unit test debug mode it does not - I am unsure why).  Unit testing was not designed for such a thing anyway.

So really, is there a way to enable Network Emulation while I debug normally, or manually enable/disable the network emulator in the background for when I need it?

For those that don't know, Network Emulator slows down traffic in/out of the machine to emulate real networked environments, it automatically starts up on the default network adapter when a test starts and closes when a test finishes

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write my own small program that starts up the emulator without the need of visual studio testing/visual studio opened. For anyone that is interested it is based off this post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lkruger/archive/2010/04/07/stand-alone-network-emulation-and-codeplex.aspx

Code is here:

http://teamtestplugins.codeplex.com/